# Django LDAP with OpenWisp Django-IPAM

Tags: django, python-3.x, ldap, django-auth-ldap, openwisp

I'm trying to setup [OpenWisp Django-IPAM](https://github.com/openwisp/django-ipam) with WebUI authentication via LDAP.  We have an OpenLDAP server within our network and I am looking to use a simple LDAP lookup to check for a valid user object for login.

I see that the API's `generics.py` file has an `authentication_classes` section, which then contains `SessionAuthentication` and `BasicAuthentication`.

Is this the same mechanism that handles the authentication for the Web UI?  Is there a way to  configure OpenWisp Django-IPAM to use something like [Django-Auth-LDAP](https://github.com/django-auth-ldap/django-auth-ldap) for authentication when logging into the web interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the authentication of the web UI of OpenWISP Django-IPAM works like default authentication of other django projects. So to use `LDAP` authentication at the `web UI`, you simply need to edit your `settings.py` file to contain the setups as shown [here](https://github.com/django-auth-ldap/django-auth-ldap).

Answer (score 1):

Something like [django-auth-ldap](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/) will help, but users will have to start a session by authenticating against the django authentication backends before being able to use the API (eg: login via the admin or provide another login view).

After a successful LDAP authentication using the method mentioned above, a new local user will be created, which maps the LDAP user.

I'm not sure if LDAP authentication requires a redirect to another application (like oauth2 or SAML) or if username and password are just redirected behind the scenes, in the latter case, [BasicAuthentication should work, I just look at its code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L53-L109) and it looks like it respect the standard django authentication framework, which supports multiple authentication backends (the LDAP backend is provided by the third party app suggested above).

A sidenote: we're moving the development of django-ipam to [openwisp-ipam](https://github.com/openwisp/openwisp-ipam), It's mostly the same. I suggest you to upgrade.